# Counting Characters with Diacritics in String using AppleScript

Tags: unicode, applescript, arabic

I'm writing an AppleScript to count characters in Unicode strings. The script works well except that it does not count Arabic diacritics, for example:

```
considering diacriticals, hyphens and punctuation
    set count_a to count characters of ("فما")
    set count_b to count characters of ("فَمّا")
end considering
```

This gives count_a = 3, which is correct. But, it also gives count_b = 3, which is wrong! count_b should be 5 because of the two extra diacritics added to the word.

Any idea how can I make AppleScript to count for diacritics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppleScript is working as designed. Like Swift and other languages that have a decent understand of Unicode, AppleScript counts glyphs, not codepoints.

If for some reason you really need to count raw codepoints, use the AppleScript-ObjC bridge to convert it to NSString (which being old and dumb has no concept of glyphs) and count that. Bear in mind that the raw codepoint count can also vary dependending on the normalization form used by a given piece of text. It really isn't a useful measure of anything other than the number of bytes used to store it.